# GitHub Organization job is missing from list of Jenkins jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am following this [Jenkins tutorial](https://youtu.be/nCKxl7Q_20I?t=975).  After installing Jenkins, I manually add the missing recommended plugins. I then try to create a new Jenkins job.  I notice that the GitHub Organization option is missing from the list.  I am using version 2.375.1 (latest as of now).  Why is this happening?  How can I fix it?  Is it missing any kind of plugin?

[image: img]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [GitHub Branch Source](https://plugins.jenkins.io/github-branch-source/) plugin is responsible for that, and is automatically installed if you selected the defaults when starting Jenkins. This is also highlighted in the [Jenkins docs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/multibranch/#organization-folders).

However, the job type is no longer `GitHub Organization`, and is instead called `Organization Folder`, which "enables Jenkins to monitor an entire GitHub Organization". The functionality is the same.

Comment: Thank you!  I spent so much time removing and re-installing Jenkins thinking that it was an error.